# Can a Birch planet send information out?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, relativity, information

Theoretically if a Birch planet is built around the event horizon of an ultra massive blackhole, if there was a planet or structure outside of range to experience time dilation, self maintained computers could calculate at a speeds of many orders of magnitudes faster (possibly infinitely? if time dilation becomes infinite) than those at the event horizon and they could keep updating the event horizon computers with calculation results at a tremendous rate, theoretically? but could those computers at range be sent information from the Birch planet?

As the escape velocity at the event horizon exceeds the speed of light due to space-time curvature could a message ever be sent out or could information even be received due to the path light takes towards the event horizon?

Comment: Time slows down the closer you get to a mass, relative to a far away observer.

Comment: You might want to look into the ergosphere of a rotating black hole. There are extra things you can do if the ergosphere is bigger than the event horizon.

Comment: @Daron Yep, I know about Penrose process and theoretical uses for ergospheres (has been a while though, will need to refresh my knowledge) I thought there was a limit of how close to the event horizon a ship could get and still escape. At a safe distance I thought time dilation is not that much

Comment: @AlanDavies I am not necessarily talking about the Penrose process. I remember [reading in a book a long time ago](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/503711.Black_Holes) that for a rotating black hole the infinite time dilation horizon is different from the point of no return event horizon. I think he called the time dilation horizon the ergosphere and said it might be the bigger of the two if the black hole is heavy enough. He also talked about traveling through time by orbiting the black hole in a certain direction.

Comment: @Daron thanks for reminding me about the ergosphere option. I forgot the talks in the past of aliens living in the ergosphere. I havent found a reliable source stating that matter is dragged at the speed of light yet but it makes sense that it could be.

Comment: You might want to edit the question to explain what a Birch planet is. Having looked it up, it seems it means a hollow shell built around the black hole, such that the surface gravity is about 1g. In that case the surface of the sphere is very far from the event horizon and the time dilation at the surface will be negligible - it will be about the same as the time dilation due to Earth's gravity well. Your question would make a lot more sense for an ordinary planet or space station orbiting the black hole just outside the event horizon, where the time dilation is much more extreme.

Comment: @N.Virgo gravitational time dilation depends on the potential, not on the field. Whether i is greater or lesser than that of Earth will depend on the size of the black hole

Comment: you may find it useful to look up the Innermost Stable Circular Orbit of a black hole (the photon sphere may also be interesting). For non-rotating black holes this is at triple the Schwarzschild radius, with unsable orbits down to double this radius. For rotating blackholes prograde orbits can be stable down almost to the Schwarzschild radius (they get closer the faster the black hole is rotating), and the ISCO for retrograde orbits can be as high as 4.5 times the Schwarzschild radius (it gets higher for faster rotating black holes)

Comment: @N.Virgo I should have explained a birch planet but I received all the answers I needed within a short time by L.Dutch and Daron. BTW even if the structure is 100,000 km thick as the BH is 0.5 light year radius the time dilation is still roughly 300 times slower, make the the structure thinner and time dilation is much more.

Comment: @AlanDavies ok, but note that if the time dilation is about 300 times then sending and receiving signals is perfectly plausible, you just have to account for the difference in wavelengths. It means you can get a 300 times speedup in computing by having your computers far away from the black hole, though that will come at the cost of a communication delay due to light having to travel between the black hole and the computers. (Also, note that Daron's answer about scrambling has no basis in science and is wrong.)

Comment: @N.Virgo Do you know how much of a delay? I did think there would be as the message will be creeping along at first against escape velocity but once it has made some distance it should pick up speed fast. Lol yeah I am aware that quantum scramble or things like event horizon firewall are just theory,I meant Darons comment about ergosphere possibilities.

Comment: The delay depends on the distance you need to go to get from ~300 times time dilation to around 1. I don't know how far that is, but if the BH is 0.5 LY in diameter I would imagine it's probably substantially longer than that, which means a delay in years, at a rough guess.

Comment: @N.Virgo I can probably work it out with online calculators, my main reason for the question was if curved space would mean a signal would just circle back to the BH but since a signal can get out, it being slowed down is not a problem. as long as the red shifting doesn't effect the quality of the message too much.

Comment: It will be slowed down by a factor of 300 at first, but c/300 is still very fast. The red shift won't degrade the signal at all, it will just change its frequency. So, e.g. you would have a microwave transmitter/receiver on the surface, but the computers would receive and transmit radio waves, at 1/300th the frequency of the microwaves. There would be no practical problems with that if the equipment is designed for it.

Answer (score 7):

If the planet it's outside the event horizon of the black hole, it can send communication outside of it.

However whoever receives it will see it extremely red shifted, due to the distortion caused by the proximity to the black hole.

If the transmission starts at the event horizon or inside it, it won't be received outside of the black hole.

Answer (score 4):

**SIGNAL CORRUPTED**

It is impossible to send information from  inside (the event horizon of) a black hole to outside. So build your shell planet outside the event horizon to allow messaging other planets.

If the shell is close to the event horizon the other planets will recieve your data in a highly scrambled form due to interference by Hawking radiation and other quantum gravitational mumbo jumbo.

Unfortunately, according to entropy physics and the conservation of information, this scrambling is a necessary feature to prevent paradox. The distortion increases in proportion to the time dilation. Make the shell twice as close to the horizon? Then there's twice as much information being sent out. But it's also twice as scrambled so the information density is the same.

The upshot is this method cannot be used to perform a superfast computation since when you transmit the answer it will be distorted. For example you have a large yes/no question that it would take 1 year to compute normally. You set the computer to emit a prolonged signal of strength 1 if the answer is yes or 0 (no signal) if the answer is no.

With no black hole you just wait a year and then measure the signal. With the black hole you can start measuring almost immediately. Only instead you are measuring the deviation from the average signal emission from the black hole. This will be so slight that you have to wait a year before you can reliably judge if the average is above the normal background.

Comment: i would like to see a citation for this scrambling.

Comment: @ths I figure if Lenny Susskind is allowed to make up black hole stuff then I should give it a go as well. Who knows -- I might be good at it.

Comment: Lenny's "make up stuff" is at a pretty high level, and backed by enough theory that it seems plausible - in particular since his "stuff" is an untested-yet hypothesis. None of this applies to you making up stuff, in particular since a black hole does NOT scramble anything; you can go down that route, but it's just technobabble and you don't even need a black hole.

Comment: @toolforger Black holes absorb stuff and then emit Hawking Radiation until they disappear. So whatever goes in gets scrambled into Hawking radiation.

Comment: @toolforger Of course I am talking about stuff near the hole and not inside. Edited the answer to mention Hawking radiation interference. Though I already think Hawking was covered under *quantum gravitational mumbo jumbo.*

Comment: Um... that's "near the event horizon", not "near the hole".

Comment: @toolforger What is the difference?

Comment: Hawking radiation is negligible for massive black holes. E.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation#Overview states that a BH at Moon mass will be in radiation equilibrium with the cosmic background radiation at 2.7K, while a Sun-mass BH would have a radiation temperature of 60 _nano_kelvin. I.e. for a "massive" black hole, you'll have much more cosmic background radiation than Hawking radiation.

Comment: The black hole itself is the singularity at the center; that's where matter density and a few other things become infinite (not time dilation, that was a mistake - that happens at the even horizon). The event horizon is where the escape velocity surpasses the speed of light; with classical models, nothing noteworthy actually happens when you cross is, except in every direction you'll see objects that are nearer to the center singularity than yourself, and you have no place to move to anymore than closer to that center.

Comment: @toolforger Lenny never talks about the singularity. I am led to believe the idea of a nugget of super dense matter in the middle and an orb of black space around is an old idea. The new idea is matter packed around the event horizon with density tending to infinity on the surface.

Answer (score 1):

A Birch planet cannot be natural, it is a megastructure that compares to a giant [Dyson Sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyson_sphere). Suppose your civilization would be able to create a Dyson Sphere the size of Neptune's orbit, it needs galactic amounts of iron to construct it. Hundreds (thousands?) of stars and gas giants would have to be dismantled to build it. But.. there are more issues.. I have to shoot down the whole idea, a Birch planet is imho an implausible construct.

### Frame challenge

**No sunshine and a lot of dangerous impacts**

In the usual Dyson sphere, you live on the inside. That works, because there is a sun inside the construct and a Dyson sphere will be rotating to generate "gravity" directed outward. A Birch planet, or Birch Dyson sphere can't possibly rotate fast enough to compensate for the inward gravitational force. As a result, you'll have to live on the outside, where you got your 1G gravity (Neptune orbit). Your construct will receive no sunshine - or too much sunshine - and it will be easily perforated with [accretion disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accretion_disk) material falling into the black hole, at near light speed.

**Time dilation**

> An object approaching the event horizon would appear to be slowing
> down as it approaches the black hole instead of speeding up as we
> would expect. This is because of time dilation, which slows the
> passing of time for an object moving close to the speed of light with
> respect to an outside observer. The object eventually would slow down
> until it stops moving when it reaches the event horizon

http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/webproj/211_fall_2014/Chris_Bon/chris_bon/blackholes.html

Yes, your computers will run faster, but that only counts for the outside observer. The inhabitants of your Birch planet won't notice that. Also, you'll have a problem with communication. For an outside observer, perceived time on your Birch planet will be [slowed down](http://ffden-2.phys.uaf.edu/webproj/211_fall_2014/Chris_Bon/chris_bon/blackholes.html). As a result, your radio waves will have a frequency well beyond the receiver capabilities of the observer. The closer your Dyson sphere will be to the event horizon, the worse that issue will become.

**Escape will be difficult**

Your civilization has built a mega structure around a black hole, they will want to do space travel. With 1G gravity, you'd assume that could be arranged. But you'll have to take into account this 1G gravity will not diminish outward, like it happens when you leave planet Earth. The 1G gravity will extend outward for many AE's, your space vessel would need to maintain escape velocity for days on end, to get away. You'll need a special drive or zillions of liters of fuel, else you can't possibly escape the place. Time dilation will spoil your space travel as well: the nearer your Birch surface is to the event horizon, the larger the time difference your space ship will perceive when it looks back. And the longer it will take your ship to return. Space travel will take forever, for anyone on your Birch planet.

Comment: Of course a birch planet is not natural, how could it be lol. Although time dilation is only relative to the observer, the computers at range will still have tens of thousands or more of years pass by for one year at the black hole relative to the at range computers.

Comment: an accretion disk is far closer to the bh than the shell. and there won't be any anyway, because the builders will have cleaned any matter that could fall in. for any civ able to assemble multiple galaxies' worth of material into a shell world, we can safely assume that space flight is a solved problem. and where would they want to go anyway? there's nothing left for millions of light years around.

Comment: Why would you make the Dyson sphere so big?

Comment: @Daron this thing is built around a super massive black hole, a galactic core like one Sagittarius-A. Its event horizon is beyond the orbit of Mercury. You need 1G, you don't want to be too near.

Comment: @Goodies You write that the outside of the Birchworld would receive no sunlight like it was a bad thing.  If people want to see, they will turn on tthe artificial lights.  Where will they get energy from?  Presumably from fusion power gnerators.

Comment: what makes the computers appear faster if the outside observer otherwise sees time slowed down?  if a 1THz CPU gets red shifted to 1MHz what's the point?

Comment: @Goodies They are not built around supermassive black holes like Sagittarius A , the tidal forces would be far too large, they are built around BH's of mass over 1.5 trillion sm. Your whole answer makes it seems like you don't understand the concept of a birch planet at all.

Comment: Its impossible for active compressive structures to be strong enough under the photon sphere, so no extreme time dilation. This puts an upper limit on BH mass if we want 1G. Even a stellar mass BH, with a radius at ~10 solar radii to get 1G, would have too way much escape velocity for chemical rockets.

Comment: @Goodies Ah, thanks. Guess I overlooked the exact size of the black hole since it wasn't obviously important. Is there a reason to use a larger hole, rather than a small one and move closer? Maybe to do with tidal foces?

Comment: @Daron see my above comment about the mass of the BH and tidal forces, goodies is wrong about, You can use astrophysical calculators to work out all the necessary details like mass, distance, escape velocity, surface gravity, time dilation etc.

Comment: @AlanDavies Why not just use a boring old 10 solar mass black hole?

Comment: @Daron Then it is no longer a birch planet, its a very large structure to avoid tidal forces ripping it apart with a very small blackhole at the centre. In those circumstances the small BH is feed matter and powers the shell with astrophysical jet power, the birch planet runs off hawkins radiation and is more of a far beyond heat death in a very expanded universe idea.

Comment: @Daron I think it is not feasible to build any structure around an "ultra massive black hole" (see opening, that was the proposal). It would be difficult to put anything near a normal black hole, because it would attract so much matter from the surroundings. A neutron star may be far more convenient ! You can mine electricity directly from its magnetic field.. btw my above frame challenge may be unapplicable, when technology level is far beyond anything we can think of.

Comment: @Goodies Is the story that building the shell at the distance to have 1g will have smaller tidal forces on a bigger black hole than a small one?

Comment: @AlanDavies Sag-A is small in respect to this.. but from this opening, it is difficult to grab the weight and  dimensions. Somewhere ([here](https://spore.fandom.com/wiki/Fiction:Virgo_Birch_Planet)) I found the surface would be 10e33 m2 (a decillion square meters) so its radius would be around 210 AE ? Which is about seven times the radius of Neptune's orbit ? do you mean that one ? I even find sources saying it's 1.3 light years in diameter..